# CSS: position div at the bottom of parent element?

Tags: css

I have a question for those frontend people out here:

How do I position a div at the bottom of its parent?

In my body-tag, which is for example 100px tall, I have a div, which is 10px tall.

How can I now make the div go to the bottom of the body tag, instead of going to the top?

I seriously can't figure that out!

Greetings
Alex

Comment: Try to avoid the F word and kindly let use see what you've tried or try give the parent (position: relative) and the child you want at tha bottom (position: absolute, bottom: 0)

Comment: make a snippet / fiddle and provide the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty easy, this is how you do it.

1. First you define `position: relative` to parent
2. Second you define `position: absolute` to child
3. Using `top, left, right, bottom` you can position child element where you want.

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    Example text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! That solved my problem!

Comment: @AlexanderRudolfvonGlahn My pleasure :) Remember to give positive votes to others aswell if they work :)

Answer (score 1):

Like that:

```css
div{
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
}

div > div{
  background-color: blue;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div>

</div>
</div>
```